# Паттерн Наблюдатель

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

В исходном варианте этот паттерн позволяет нескольким наблюдателям получать сообщения об изменении состояния одного объекта. А можно ли сделать что-то похожее, но чтобы было наоборот: один наблюдатель получает сообщения об изменении состояния нескольких объектов? Причём на сообщения от разных объектов наблюдатель должен реагировать по разному. У меня есть одна идея по этому поводу. В методе обработки сообщения передавать параметр, показывающий, какое именно событие его вызвало, и на этом основании вызывать обработчики. Возможно ли сделать это более красиво?

Comment: Можно.
Если Java - можно ознакомиться по очень хорошей книге:
Фримен Эр., Фримен Эл., Сьерра К., Бейтс Б. - Паттерны проектирования - 2011

Comment: Какая разница - java или нет

В многих толковых книгах по ооп для примеров используется именно java  =)

Comment: а почему вы не хотите сделать для каждого объекта был свой набор наблюдателей?

Comment: А что тут можно еще придумать? Либо один метод на все наблюдаемые объекты с обработкой параметра, либо по одному специальному методу на каждый объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал более банально: у каждого объекта есть своё событие (конкретное для данного объекта), а наблюдатель всего лишь подписывается на все нужные ему события объектов и реагирует нужным способом на каждое по разному (под каждое событие свой обработчик). После чего не нужно никому ничего передавать, делать ветвления, дополнительные "перечисления" и "свитч".

Answer (score 1):

каждый объект может быть наблюдателем и оповещать другие объекты. Как говорили выше, можно прочитать в книжке. Там хорошо расписано.

Comment: Читал эту книгу. Там описана ситуация "один объект - много наблюдателей", а мне нужно наоборот, "много объектов - один наблюдатель", причём для каждого объекта свой обработчик.

Answer (score 1):

Например в C# для этого завожу специальный класс:

```
public sealed class MutableData<T>
{
    private T value;

    public MutableData()
    {   
            value = default(T);
    }

    public MutableData(T value)
    {   
            this.value = value;
    }

    public event EventHandler DataChanged;

    public T get()
    {   
            return this.value;
    }

    public void set(T newValue, object sender)
    {   
            value = newValue;
            if (DataChanged != null)
            {   
                    DataChanged(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
            }   
    }   
}
```

После чего любой объект можно обернуть и подписаться на изменения его значений (разумеется, если они производятся через метот set).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй посмотреть в сторону АОП (аспектно-ориентированное программирование), его философия близка к тому что тебе нужно

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте поправить: классы на которые подписываются, называются **субъектами** (Subject). А не объектами, как в вопросе. Подробнее здесь: https://pcask.ru/programmirovanie/pattern-observer/

Таким образом, задача должна звучать так: один наблюдатель получает сообщения об изменении состояния нескольких субъектов.

Но здесь нет проблем. В самом простом случае на события данных субъектов подписывается один наблюдатель. Не надо другие классы подписывать на эти события. Так решается задачаю.

Если важно обеспечить гарантированно отсутствие утечки информации о событиях, то применяется система с открытым ключом (известным субъекту). И закрытым, которы известен только наблюдателю. Таким образом расшифровать данные не сможет никто кроме наблюдателя. Правда, тут возникает один нюанс: факт получения сигнала от субъекта все же перехватить можно. Поэтому надо просто вернуться к варианту выше: один не допускать других наблюдателей к этим субъектам.